# How do I read IE Cookie timestamps as DateTime?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, datetime, cookies, datetime-format

I was trying to read IE cookie file using C#

I am stuck with how to read the datetime inside the file.

They divide the datetime into 2 lines like this

```
481435648

30298937
```

or

```
1100239232

30151908
```

I have tried all methods to convert this to readable date time but I failed. I have read about FileTime, nanoseconds and ticks, and none of those got me on the right path.

Comment: "They divide the datetime into 2 lines" .... who is They??? 
You're reading a cookie not created by you?! so how do you know that it's a date inside??

Comment: 2GDev Don't use so much `?`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>According to [this post](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5) there is only one field for expiration date (the second one could be the cookie value ? )and to read it, you can use something like</strike>

```
DateTime expires = new DateTime(1970, 1,1).AddSeconds(secondsFromCookie);
Console.WriteLine(expires);
```

The above is applicable only for netscape cookie file format.
For IE use

```
        int eLow = 481435648;
        int eHigh = 30298937;
        double seconds = 1e-7*(eHigh*Math.Pow(2, 32) + eLow) - 11644473600;
        DateTime expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(seconds);
```

[Source of the formula](http://weitips.blogspot.com/2006/04/cookie-file-format-of-internet.html)

Comment: Do you know how can i make the reverse .
Convert DateTime to this 2 lines integer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
long leastSignificant = 481435648;
long mostSignificant = 30298937;
var fileTime = (mostSignificant << 32) + leastSignificant;

DateTime cookieTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(fileTime);
```